# Protecting the paint using a carport for winter storage

Tags: paint, winter, cold, storage

I'm considering buying a summer vehicle that I would like to store for winter, but I don't have an optimal storage solution.  There's no climate-controlled storage facility nearby.

What I do have is a steel carport that can I can fully enclose to block sunlight and precipitation while allowing for minimal airflow.  I live in central/western Canada, our winters are **cold** and dry.  Stretches of -40C are not uncommon, and typical temperatures hover around -15C for several months.

Assuming I have taken all the proper steps for preparation and can prevent critters, the only thing I have left to concern myself with is frost build-up on the paint during the early and late parts of the winter season (and sometimes during warm spells).  At times, the frost melts faster than it evaporates and leaves spots on the paint.  I won't have the opportunity to wash it for months due to freezing temperatures.

Is there anything I can do to either prevent frost with this storage option or prepare the paint in a way that water spots won't damage the finish?

Comment: This is probably not the response you were looking for, but it's not just the paint you have to worry about. Not sure if you've considered this already, but you'll need to find somewhere else to store the tires - [many summer compounds aren't designed to handle extreme cold](https://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=220), as they can crack and lose their grip, even after the winter has passed. Because of this, I can really only recommend finding some sort of heated garage, or coming up with your own solution to heat your carport.

Comment: @Kitsunemimi: thanks, I had anticipated that.  My plan would be to purchase a cheap set of wheels & tires for it to sit on in winter and keep the summer tires in climate-controlled storage.  I doubt there's any way to sufficiently heat a steel carport when the temperature is that far below zero.